# variables keep changing back to their original value inside a while loop

Tags: python

i am doing the MITx 6.00.01x course and i am on the second problem set on the 3rd problem and i am stuck. 
my code:

```
    balance = 320000
    annualInterestRate = 0.2
    monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate) / 12.0
    monthlyFixedPayment = 0
    empBalance = balance
    lowerBound = round((balance)/12,2)
    upperBound = (balance*(1+monthlyInterestRate)**12)/12
    monthlyFixedPayment = round( ( (lowerBound+upperBound)/2) ,2)
    while tempBalance != 0: 
        monthlyFixedPayment = round( ( (lowerBound+upperBound)/2) ,2)  
        for m in range(12) :
            tempBalance -= monthlyFixedPayment 
            tempBalance += (monthlyInterestRate)*(tempBalance)
            tempBalance = round(tempBalance,2) 
        if tempBalance > 0:
            lowerBound = round(monthlyFixedPayment,2)
            tempBalance = balance
        elif tempBalance < 0: 
            upperBound = round(monthlyFixedPayment,2)
            tempBalance = balance

    print('Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(monthlyFixedPayment,2)))
```

my code uses bisection search to generate the monthlyFixedPayment but after i get to the lines at the end that changes the upperBound or lowerBound values and then start the loop again, the lowerBound and upperBound values reset to their values to the ones outside the loop. does anyone knows how to prevent this?

Comment: Should `empBalance` be `tempBalance` in line 5?

Comment: yeah that's not in the original code i accidently deleated it while copying the code

Comment: Variables don't change their values by themselves. There's no way to prevent it because it doesn't happen.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe: http://ideone.com/izgkqi. The script fails because the loop never ends.

Comment: well i checked it and the upperBound value should be changed at the end of the first loop, it does and then it changes back to the value outside the loop. why does that happens?

Comment: @Barmar well can you help me fix it?

Comment: I can't help you fix something that doesn't happen. Please post the actual code. Don't retype it, because you make copying errors. Just use copy and paste.

Comment: @Barmar i found the problem, when i use the round it transforms the number "29157.095" to the number "29157.1" but i need it to be "29157.09" do you know how to round it to that number?

Comment: The actual value of the number is probably something like `29157.0950000001`, so it's closer to `29157.10` than `29157.09`. Floating point is approximate, so you have to be able to deal with inaccuracies like this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: That explains why the loop never ends, but it has nothing to do with the variables being reset to their initial values.